# Laravel Eloquent Join with SUM()

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to convert MySQL query to Laravel Eloquent, but it is throwing error.
The query is like this:

```
(
    SELECT
        p.id AS product_id,
        p.name AS product_name,
        SUM(s.quantity) AS product_quantity
    FROM
        products AS p
    INNER JOIN
        stocks AS s
        ON p.id = s.product_id
    GROUP BY
        p.id
);
```

Comment: can you add the eloquent & the error ?

Comment: $stocks = $this->model->select(
   "products.id as product_id", 
   "products.name as product_name",
   "SUM(quantity) as product_quantity")
   ->join("products", "products.id", "=", "stocks.product_id")
   ->get()
   ->groupBy("products.id");

Comment: Error is: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM(quantity)' in 'field list' (SQL: select `products`.`id` as `product_id`, `products`.`name` as `product_name`, `SUM(quantity)` as `product_quantity` from `stocks` inner join `products` on `products`.`id` = `stocks`.`product_id`)

Comment: The issue is simple, just use `selectRaw` for the aggregate column (`SUM(quantity) AS product_quantity`).

Comment: it appears from the error that you don't specify the table for quantity in the eloquent and that is what causing the error. 
so modify it in the eloquent and I think it will work

Comment: Thanks for the comments :)
$stocks = $this->model->select("products.id as product_id", "products.name as product_name")
  ->selectRaw("SUM(quantity) as product_quantity")
  ->join("products", "products.id", "=", "stocks.product_id")
  ->groupBy("products.id")->get();
This solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
DB::query()
    ->select(
        'p.id AS product_id',
        'p.name AS product_name',
    )
    ->selectRaw('SUM(s.quantity) AS product_quantity') // need to use selectRaw for aggregate values like this.
    ->from('products', 'p')
    ->join('stocks as s', 'p.id', 's.product_id')
    ->groupBy('p.id')
    ->get();
```

Using the syntax in your comment:

```php
$this->model
     ->select("products.id as product_id", "products.name as product_name")
     ->selectRaw("SUM(quantity) as product_quantity") // select() doesn't work for aggregate values
     ->join("products", "products.id", "=", "stocks.product_id")
     ->groupBy("products.id")
     ->get()
```